# Responsive sticky sidebar, need to update width

Tags: responsive-design, sidebar, sticky

I've got a responsive sticky sidebar started here: http://codepen.io/cmegown/pen/fjqzH. I've got the sticky part down, and it's responsive in relation to the width of the original viewport width. However, if you scroll down and then change the viewport size you'll see that the width of the sidebar does not change.

I know I need to update the `sidebarWidth` variable, but I'm sure exact how/where to do that.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:**
This one kind of got left behind amid some other projects, but I'm back to finish this. I got a little further, but still can't seem to figure out how to update the sidebar width if the user scrolls down the page then expands their browser (or rotates their device). I have some commented code in the JS panel where I left off.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the width calculation in your scroll function.

```
$(function () {
  // cache selectors
  var wrapper = $('.wrapper');
  var sidebar = $('.sidebar');

  // get some maths

  var sidebarTop = sidebar.offset().top;
  var sidebarOffset = 25; // is .wrapper padding

  // sticky logic
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var sidebarWidth = Math.round(wrapper.width() * 0.3); // is .sidebar width
    if (sidebarTop < (windowTop + sidebarOffset)) {
      sidebar.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: sidebarOffset,
        width: sidebarWidth
      })
    } else {
      sidebar.css({
        position: 'static',
        width: '30%' // original CSS value
      })
    }
  })
})
```

There's a little bit of overhead there, since it has to calculate the width every time you scroll. The alternative would be to put it into a `$(window).resize()` function so it figures out the width when you resize the window.

Comment: Is there any live demo?

Comment: However, I tested it using Chrome, it works fine, However, when resizing the browser's window (maximize, minimize) without reloading the page, the size of the sidebar remains as it is.

Comment: @TimWasson thanks for your input. Unfortunately when you make changes to someone else's pen the changes don't actually save, you need to fork it and make the changes there. If you could do that so I can see what you mean, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't just copy/paste the code I put above into your pen, but here's the forked one: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iuCmc .

Comment: @TimWasson I figured that's what you did, thanks for getting back to me. It's close, but if you scroll down a ways (so the sidebar "sticks") and then resize the viewport you'll see the `sidebarWidth` doesn't update.

Comment: I revisited this issue, but couldn't resolve it. Any more ideas?